# Outside click directive fire event on wrong element Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, directive

I have created a directive for catching outside click of an element using Angular6 like as follows.

```
import { Directive, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appOutsideclick]'
})
export class OutsideclickDirective {
  @Output() outsideclick = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(public eRef: ElementRef) { }
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if (this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) === false) {
      this.outsideclick.emit(event);
    }
  }
}
```

It is working well except if we have an element inside of the container which is hidden using `*ngIf` and if we click when it is shown will trigger the event.

```
    <div appOutsideclick (outsideclick)="someFunction1()">
      <span *ngIf="showMe" click="someFunction2()">This element shown after ng init based on a condition </span> 
This text is alwaise shown
    </div>
```

If we click the span element, It fires `outsideclick` event. How is it possible to fix this issue?

**Note:**
I know in this example , It can make working using `[hidden]="!showMe"` , But this is just an example for easy understanding the issue.my html is complex and contain components from node module,so I cannot apply the `hidden` everywere

Answer (score 1):

Really not ideal, but should work. You could consider using an id or a class rather than tagName to filter out the element.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if (
      this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) === false
      && event.target.tagName !== 'SPAN'
    ) {
      this.outsideclick.emit(event);
    }
  }
```